# rake aborted! ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. - no exisiting project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have looked at a number of similar questions on this topic, however all of them centre around the idea of this error appearing when in a current project. The rake aborted! error happens when I am trying to create a new project:

```
$ rails new my_new_app
(in /Users/vitalbone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails-0.9.5)
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.
/Users/vitalbone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rails-0.9.5/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/vitalbone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/vitalbone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How (and where) do I make the necessary edits to fix this issue?

I have also uninstalled & reinstalled different versions of rake to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty old version of Rails you've got there - v0.9.5 is from January 2005. Since you're running Ruby 2.1.0, why not install the the Rails 4.0.4 gem from March 14?

It's as simple as:

`gem install rails`

I think that will help deal with the obsolescence issue.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Unfortunately when I tried that, the same error message appeared after the install. In fact, the same error message appears after any rails call. e.g: `rails --version` emits the same error.

Comment: wow - perhaps try uninstalling the gem - or running gem update rails? Just a shot in the dark at this point.